# Can you use pending intents with localbroadcasts?

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-pendingintent

I am interested in using pending intents with local broadcasts.
To make myself clear, I am using the following for registering receivers and sending broadcast: `android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager`.

I have a local broadcast receiver in a service which works. I am trying to send local broadcasts from a custom notification layout which includes click-able items.

The local broadcast receiver - just receives simple action intents.
I was trying something like this to no avail:

```
Intent backintent = new Intent("GOTO_START_BROADCAST");
PendingIntent backIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, backintent, 0);
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView1, backIntent);
```

Comment: What's wrong with using an IntentService instead of a LocalBroadcast for this use case?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> I am interested in using pending intents with local broadcasts.

That is not possible.

The point behind a `PendingIntent` is to allow *some other process* to perform an action you request, such as sending a broadcast.

The point behind `LocalBroadcastManager` is to keep broadcast *within your process*.

Hence, a `PendingIntent` can issue a regular broadcast, but not one via `LocalBroadcastManager`.

Comment: is there a way for me to have a facility like `PendingIntent.UPDATE_CURRENT` etc., using `LocalBroadcastManager`? Basically when there is a lot of events happening at once, I would like to send just one `LocalBroadcast` instead of one for each event. How would I accomplish that using a `LocalBroadcast`.

Comment: @500865: `PendingIntent` cannot work with `LocalBroadcastManager`. A `PendingIntent` is designed to work across process boundaries; `LocalBroadcastManager` is designed to *not* work across process boundaries.

Comment: This is why my `BroadcastReceiver` wasn't receiving broadcasts. Solved by using the conventional `BroadcastManager`.